# How do I hide decimal numbers the correct way?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this method to hide the decimal numbers in a page.

CSS code:

```
span {
    clip-path: inset(0 2.1ch 0 0);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<span>$91,118.91</span>
```

The result should look like this: `$91,118`

**The problem: Not all numbers have the same size for `width` (e.g. number 1 and 9)**

Is there anyway to go around this? or I'm doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Try using JavaScript will save your valuable time

Comment: unfortunately I don't know JavaScript :(

Comment: Why down vote?!

Comment: btw `91,118.91` is NOT `91,118` it is  `91,119`. You NEED to use javascript when dealing with numbers, learn it.

Comment: But it will be difficult solving this type of problem with CSS and having little bit of knowledge about JavaScript will be always helpful

Comment: @ikiK I know it's not the same, but the numbers doesn't need to be 100% correct

Comment: Everyone ain't so polite as you are new user they shouldn't use down vote. Your question already have answer somewhere in stack.

Comment: The down vote (note mine) is because this is just wrong way to do things. Bad rounding method by using means (CSS), and its bad wanting a wrong round number result. And numbers need to be 100% correct  in any case.

Comment: CSS is using only for element styling, your question has to be solved on the back-end or by JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS, there are a lot of ways to do it...

```js
const n = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

Array.from(n).forEach(v => v.innerText = v.innerText.split('.')[0]);
```

```html
<span>$71,558.84</span>
```

Comment: OP probably has more than one `span` with decimal points, I think an ID-based element picker would be better as an example.

Comment: @Jabster28 select by tag returns a collection of HTML elements, id based will return only first matched id, because id has to be unique for the document...this example has the purpose to show "how to get rid of decimal numbers"...

Comment: Please also add a proper rounding method example for user to see how simple and correct way would be. Result should be 71,559

Comment: I changed from getElementsByTagName to getElementsByClassName and it works like magic :D thanks

Comment: @ikiK it's the easier way without parsing and other things. We can't use parseFloat if we want to use parsing, have to strip dollar sign then use type conversion or `parseFloat` then use one of the round methods and then return back dollar sign. As I understood he is looked for removing these numbers not rounding and I gave the solution that he is looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today for a HTML-based report (generated by ASP.NET Core, it works with any HTML generator) that needed to toggle decimal digits in table-cells (e.g. to reduce visual-noise and hide irrelevant low-significance numbers, and to be more legible on smnaller screens, etc).

As with the OP, I'm rendering every numeric value in its own `<span>` - so my initial thought was to render the decimal digits in a child `<span>` that can be toggled using CSS (or JS, if necessary), something like this interactive snippet:

### Attempt 1:

```css
#toggleDecimals:checked ~ * .amount > .decimals {
    display: inline;
}

#toggleDecimals:not(:checked) ~ * .amount > .decimals {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleDecimals" />
<label for="toggleDecimals">Click me to toggle decimal digits</label>

<br />

<span class="usd-amount">
    <span class="symbol">$</span>
    <span class="amount">123<span class="decimals">.45</span></span>
</span>

<br />

<span class="usd-amount">
    <span class="amount">99<span class="decimals">.99</span></span>
    <span class="symbol">%</span>
</span>


<br />

<span class="usd-amount">
    <span class="amount">1609<span class="decimals">.34</span></span>
    <span class="symbol">m</span>
</span>
```

But there's **two** main problems with the above concept:

1. The approach above simply *truncates* numbers, whereas users will expect numbers to be appropriately rounded: for example, the value `99.99 %` should be displayed as `100 %` *and not* `99 %` - and `$123.55` becomes `$124` and not `$123`.
2. I would need to isolate only the decimal point and decimal digits so they can be rendered in their own `<span>`, which is surprisingly difficult: you can't use your language's built-in `sprintf` [or standard numeric formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) features because (in C#/.NET at least), given a `Decimal` value and the current `CultureInfo`, you can't (easily) get *only*  the decimal point and decimal digits isolated from other parts (like currency-symbols, posiitve/negative, etc, especially if it's using "parentheses-means-negative"-style formatting).

### Attempt 2:

But I realised that I can use CSS's `content: attr()` property function to *replace* the entire decimal-formatted text with a correctly rounded, non-decimal version, without needing to faff around with extracting digits or reimplementing structured formatting by myself.

There are some caveats, but nowhere near as bad as the problems with the first approach:

- Using `content: attr()` only works on the `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements: you can't use `content: "new text";` or `content: attr(data-new-text);` to replace an HTML element's text-content <sub>(but `content: url("image.png");` does work on normal elements, curious).</sub>

  - This means having to use an inner `<span>` so we can hide the original text with `display: none;` or similar.
- Furthermore, text in `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements cannot be selected by the user....

  - This *would be* a problem if the rounded-numbers represented radically different content compared to what they replaced - however in this particular case, it means that (provided the inner `<span>` is hidden using `font-size: 0;` and **not** using `display: none;`) then when the user drags-and-selects the text they'll still end-up copying the original values, which is desirable behaviour.

    - Surprisingly, setting an explicit `user-select: all` or `user-select: text` on the element or the pseudoelements has no effect, which is unfortunate.

Anyway, here's a working example:

```css
#toggleDecimals:checked ~ * .amount {
}

#toggleDecimals:not(:checked) ~ .value > .amount::before {
    content: attr(data-round);
  
/*
    * Unfortunately, we can't use `content: attr(data-round);`  on the `.amount` element's style, because `content:` cannot be used to replace text on normal elements, while `content: url()` (for images) does work on normal elements, but `content: "new text";` and `content: attr(data-foo);` only work on pseudoelements.
*/
}

#toggleDecimals:not(:checked) ~ .value > .amount > span {
    /* Don't use `display: none;`: it prevents users selecting+copying the original text, as ::before/::after cannot be selected, even with `user-select: all`. */
    font-size: 0;
}

#toggleDecimals:not(:checked) ~ .value2 > .amount {
    font-size: 0;
}
#toggleDecimals:not(:checked) ~ .value2 > .amount::before {
    font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleDecimals" checked="checked" />
<label for="toggleDecimals">Click me to toggle decimal digits</label>

<br />

<span class="value usd-amount">
    <span class="symbol">$</span>
    <span class="amount" data-round="123"><span>123.35</span></span>
</span>

<br />

<span class="value usd-amount">
    <span class="symbol">$</span>
    <span class="amount" data-round="124"><span>123.55</span></span>
</span>

<br />

<span class="value perc-amount">
    <span class="amount" data-round="100"><span>99.99</span></span>
    <span class="symbol">%</span>
</span>


<br />

<span class="value length-amount">
    <span class="amount" data-round="1609"><span>1609.34</span></span>
    <span class="symbol">m</span>
</span>

<br />

<span class="value value2">
    <span class="amount" data-round="1609">1609.34</span>
    <span class="symbol">m</span>
</span>
```